# "Failed to read font" while embedding font

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm trying to embed a font in the PDF output using FOP 2.3.

This is my config file:

```
<font embed-url="D:/fop-2.3/fop/Fonts/helr46w.ttf" kerning="yes" sub-font="Helvetica">
    <font-triplet name="Helvetica" style="italic" weight="normal"/>
</font>
```

This is the error I get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to read font file D:/fop- 2.3/fop/Fonts/helr46w.ttf
at org.apache.fop.fonts.LazyFont.load(LazyFont.java:132)
at org.apache.fop.fonts.LazyFont.getAscender(LazyFont.java:235)
at org.apache.fop.fonts.Font.getAscender(Font.java:120)
at
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: I am also facing the same error and stuck at this. BTW I chose FOP 2.3 just to use the property "border-radius". Is there a way to achieve this in FOP 1.1?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue running FOP 2.3 and had to put file:/ in front of the filepath

Answer (score 0):

The most relevant part of the error message is this one:

> `Failed to read font file D:/fop- 2.3/fop/Fonts/helr46w.ttf`

FOP is not able to reach the file it should embed:

- verify that the file path is correct (is that a space in the path?)
- verify that the file permissions allow FOP to read it

Comment: how to verify that the file permission in FOP

Comment: The same (.xconf) conf file is working fine with FOP 1.1
Not working with FOP 2.3